# Help to understand the notion of quotient space

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading up on quotient spaces and quotient maps. For the sake of simplicity please refer to the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)).

I want to see how this works by looking at an example, specifically the map $q: [0,1] \to [0,1]/\{0,1\}$. A couple of questions:

- I understand the domain to be the set of real numbers from 0 to 1 (inclusive), and the co-domain to be the set of real numbers from 0 to 1 (exclusive), union with the set $\{0,1\}$, i.e. $img(q) = \{\{0,1\},0.000...,...,0.999...\}$. Is this correct?
- Are we considering $[0,1] \text{ and } [0,1]/\{0,1\}$ as subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$? If so, are they endowed with the subspace topology?
- Irrespective of the answer to the question above, what are the open sets in the domain and the co-domain?
- The article say that $[0,1]/\{0,1\}$ is homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$. How is it so? Can a specific homeomorphism be given here?

=========================================
**Edit:** the questions above have become more clear to me, thanks to the help of some users. I'd like to cite another example on the same topic, with a few questions:

[image]

I understand the co-domain to be 
$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} = \{[0],...,[r]|\text{where } r \lt 1\}$,
while the domain $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the usual open sets $(a,b)$.

If we equip $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ with the quotient topology (i.e. $O/p$ as it is denoted in the definition below), it would follow that the open sets in this space $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ should also be sets of the form $(a,b), 0 \leq a \lt b \leq 1$.

But if we just consider it as a space without any relation to the domain $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. its topology is $O_1$, as it is denoted in the definition below), then it seems the open sets would be of the form $[a,b), 0 \leq a \lt b \leq 1$.

Hence $O/p \neq O_1$.

Where did I go wrong with my analysis?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometric picture you should have in mind is gluing together the two endpoints of a line segment to get a circle.

Yes the image is $(0,1) \cup \{\{0,1\}\}$.
$[0,1]$ is is being considered under the subspace topology (of either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$). A priori, the quotient space is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, we have to prove that it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$.
The open sets in $[0,1]$ follow from the above definition.

Here is what defines the quotient topology on the image: $V$ is open in the image iff $q^{-1}[V]$ is open in the domain.

Consider a subset $V$ of $(0,1) \cup \{\{0,1\}\} $.

If $\{0,1\} \notin V$, then $V$ is open in $(0,1) \cup \{\{0,1\}\}$ iff $V$ is open in $[0,1]$.

If  $\{0,1\} \in V$, then $V$ is open in $(0,1) \cup \{\{0,1\}\}$ iff $(V \setminus \{\{0,1\}\}) \cup \{0,1\} $ is open in $[0,1]$.

The homeomorphism  $(0,1) \cup \{\{0,1\}\} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ is given by
$x \mapsto (\cos{2\pi x},\sin{2\pi x})$ for $x \neq \{0,1\}$ and $x \mapsto (1,0)$ when $ x = \{0,1\}$

Edit: In fact the image of $q$ should be $\{\{x\} : x \in (0,1)\} \cup \{\{0,1\}\}$. But since we are going to give it a topology, we might as well have the image  to be $(0,1) \cup \{\{0,1\}\}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the case of $\{0,1\} \in V$, could you explain why you used the notation $(V \backslash \{0,1\}) \cup \{0,1\}$? Also, still in this case, following your argument, I assume that the open sets in the co-domain would be $V = \{\{0,1\} \cup (a,b)\}, \text{ where } 0 \leq a \lt b \leq 1$, and $V = \{\{0,1\}\}$. Am I correct?

Comment: I have edited the answer to correct my error. Now, we are removing the element $\{0,1\}$ and adding the elements $0$ and $1$. This should clear up some stuff.

Comment: Thanks. Could you specify what form the open sets would take? This would make it easier for me to figure out the rest. I just want to be sure. Also please look at the edit in my question above if possible.

Comment: Your basic open sets are $(a,b) \ 0<a<b<1$ and $(c,1) \cup (0,d) \cup \{0,1\}$. You get your arbitrary open sets to be unions of sets of the above kind.

Comment: @ensbana I don't see $O_1$ in any definition. Regardless, note that in $O/p, [0,0.1) \cup (0.9,1) $ is an open set according to the defintion.

Comment: $O/p$ in the edit is defined as 
$O/p = \{U \cup \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Z} \ | \ can^{-1}(U) \text{ open in } \mathbb{R} \}$. Take the set $[0,0.1)$ in $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Z} \ $ 
as an example. I understand 
$can^{-1}([0,0.1)) = \{...[-1,-0.9) \cup[0,0.1) \cup [1,1.1) \cup [2,2.1)  \cup...\}$. 
If this set is to be considered open in $\mathbb{R}$, does it mean $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the open sets of the form $[a,b)$, and not the usual topology (with open sets (a,b)?

Comment: @ensbana First off, $\mathbb{R}$ is being taken in the usual topology. Second, I am not saying $[0,0.1)$ is open. I am saying $[0,0.1) \cup (0.9,1)$ is open. $can^{-1}([0,0.1) \cup (0.9,1)) = \dots{} (-0.1,0.1) \cup (0.9,1.1) \cup (1.9,2.1) \dots{})$

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for being not thorough with my reading. $O_1$ is actually not defined, but it appears in the definition of quotient map in the last picture. Not much is said about $O_1$ so I don't know what its open sets are?

Comment: This is more of an abstract definition of a quotient map. It goes like this - consider a map to a set (Y) with some topology $O_1$. We know that any map (from a top. space) to a set (Y) can be given a quotient topology, in this case $O/p$. So when do call the map $p$, a quotient map (here $p$ is considered as a map between two top. spaces instead of a map from a top. space to a set)? Precisely when $O_1= O/p$.

Answer (score 2):

img q = { {0,1}, {r} : r in (0,1) } which are the equivalence classes of the equivalence relation defining the quotient space:
x ~ y iff x,y in {0,1} or x = y.

[0,1] is a closed subspace of R.  The quotient is not a subspace of R nor R$^2$.

U is an open set of the quotient iff f$^{-1}$(U) in an open set of [0,1].

Comment: Thanks. Could you please look at the edit of my above? It'd be best if you can specify what form the open sets would take. This would make it easier for me to figure out the rest.